# C# linq filter array of ints

Tags: c#, linq

Given an array of ints:

```
int[] testInt = new int[] { 2, 3, 1, 0, 0 };
```

How can I return an array of ints where each element meets a criteria?

To return all elements are greater than zero, I've tried

```
int[] temp = testInt.Where(i => testInt[i] > 0).ToArray();
```

...but this only returns an index with 4 elements of `2, 1, 0, 0`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i` is the array element:

```
int[] temp = testInt.Where(i => i > 0).ToArray();
```

`Where` accepts a function (`Func<int, bool>`) then `Where` iterates through each element of the array and checks if the condition is true and yields that element. When you write `i =>` the `i` is the element inside the array. As if you wrote:

```
foreach(var i in  temp)
{
   if( i > 0)
      // take that i
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The element you pass on the lambda expression (`i` on the sample), it is your element on the collection, in the case, the `int` value. For sample:

```
int[] temp = testInt.Where(i => i > 0).ToArray();
```

You also can use by index passing the lambda expression which takes the index on the element. It's not a good pratice, *using the element you already have on the scope is the best choice*, but for other samples, you could use the index. For sample:

```
int[] temp = testInt.Where((item, index) => testInt[index] > 0).ToArray();
```

Comment: The second example here is good for pointing towards the situation where each index meets a criteria, such as `int[] temp = testInt.Where((item, index) => index < testInt.Length - 1).ToArray();` to copy all but the last element. The question involves criteria with elements, but I think this answer gets bonus points because it points how to deal with criteria with indexes and elements.

Comment: There are a lot of methods on `Linq` specification that allows you to take the element and its index. I hope help you anyway. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] temp = testInt.Where(p=>p>0).ToArray()
```